# Running latest version of Auto Desk Viewer on React Native - Cookie error

Tags: react-native, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

For the past days I totally dived into Forge API and managed to get t[his old-repository that works with React Native and AutoDesk Viewer](https://github.com/wallabyway/forgeApp) to work with some URNs I translated, felt like a big achievement but I'm looking to deploy a fast performance app and this example uses a really early version of Auto Desk Viewer (2.17).

So I manage to, following the example on the API latest version, [get the autodesk viewer working on my Browser.](https://gist.github.com/JoaoPedroRodrigues/9a8dc810795dfa599030f3ab024c3848)

With that working my next logical step would be to substitute the code on [styles.viewerHTML](https://github.com/wallabyway/forgeApp/blob/master/js/styles.js) with that one I mentioned above.

The problem is, I get this error: [Chrome Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2U5W.png)

Is there a work around to this error?

I notice that in the [API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/) is mentioned that Initializer has some cookie settings, is there a way to turn it off? As it is probably why I'm getting this errors.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
Putting a [snack io](https://snack.expo.io/@jaype9/autodesk-viewer-react-native) to make easier for everyone to help on this issue.
While setting this snack io both versions turned to be working on iPhone, but android still only works with the old version.

To get the Snack IO to work you have to put an URN and a token of yours on lines 15 and 16.

```js
const urn = 'YOUR-URN'; // REPLACE WITH YOUR URN
const token = 'YOUR-TOKEN'; // REPLACE WITH YOUR TOKEN
```

On line 27 you can choose whether you want the old version (version2dot17) or the latest version of version 7.

```js
source={{ html: version2dot17}} // latestVersion or version2dot17
```

Comment: what's the contents of your cookie when this happens? when I examine my mine created by a viewer i don't see any data urls in there though... if you break on the offending line what data urls is viewer attempting to set? and what version is your chrome? try upgrade if it's too early (than 70)? does it work on firefox etc?

Comment: Hey Bryan! Just checked my cookies, there is nothing, completely empty. When I checked the offending line it seems like it's trying to set this: 
`_document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+";"+domain+"path=/";`

Chrome version is "74.0.3729.185" and I couldn't find a way to make android web view run on firefox instead of chrome, but the iPhone version is running in a safari webview and it doesn't work either. (I just can't give you the details on that one yet because I still have to find a way to debug Safari WebView from a Windows PC)

Comment: So, while I was setting up a snack io to make it easier for everyone to work together on this, I found out that actually both versions (the older one and the latest) work on my iPhone (not sure why I did not work before). But on the android it's still not working. Btw, there is a snack io on the main question for running code sample!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Specify a `baseUri` to enable cookies when using html content string - cookies are tied to domains:

```
<WebView
  source={{html, baseUrl:'http://localhost'}}
//...
```

If you'd like to stop Viewer from setting the cookies turn off `useCookie` for the built-in `i18n`:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.i18n.options.useCookie=false;

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer( ...
```

See further discussion [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/webview-html-error-cookies-are-disabled-inside-data-urls/30502) on the cookies error when rendering from html string.

**Original Answer**

Tested the latest Viewer but unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the same issue - one thing I did differently was I put the HTML content in a separate file and instead of a string:

```
  <WebView source={{ uri: '...'}} ...
```

Managed to get it to work on my Android Nougat:

[image]

No errors in the console log either:

[image]